# C# DataTable issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable

I have a query which I'm struggling with as I'm not very apt at Linq. I have a datatable with some of its Datacolumn defined as readonly. How do I get Datatable with columns which are non readonly in C#. I don't want to hardcode column names because with change in dropdown, my datatable is going to change with different columns. After that I search through those non readonly columns to get some values.

I tried in many ways like DataTableCld.AsIenumerable().where(x =>x.Table.columns.IsReadOnly.Equals(true));

Its coming as null. Please tell me whats wrong with above code. Can anyone tell whats the right way. Thanks for your time?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve. Do you want the set of columns that are NOT readonly? By the way, what difference it makes if they are readonly?

Comment: @Steve from what I gather he wants to get a Datatable with columns that are NOT read only. I think he is going to have a dropdownlist with table names, or so, and when he selects a table there, he wants to render the columns, but he doesn't want to hardcode the column names so he wants a generic way to get the columns that are not readonly.

Comment: Hi @Dzyann, what you said is correct. But my dropedown will have some other values. Based on that value change, I populate different data in datatable which is bound to WPF datagrid. I want to populate Datagrid based on text input typed in Find window dialog . So datagrid will have those all data matching in non readonly columns values.

Comment: Well as far as I can gather, you have to explain what framework or class, etc you are using to get the data from the database in order for people to help you.